# How to scan with Canon TS 5150 Printer/Scanner

Tags: macbook-pro

I just purchased my TS5150 printer/scanner. I can print wirelessly just fine. However I cannot SCAN. I cannot scan using either "printers and scanners from the "system Preferences" menu OR from the IJ scan Utilities.
Each time I get a 21345 error "failed to open a connection to the device"..
I have removed and re-installed the entire application.  I have a Macbook Air Catalina 10.15.7.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

According to the information on Canons website this device is only supported over AirPrint (which doesn't support scanning). It seems to be [supported by Vuescan](https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/canon_ts5150.html#technical-information) though:

> VueScan is compatible with the Canon TS5150 on Windows x86, Windows x64, Windows RT, Windows 10 ARM, Mac OS X and Linux

I'm just a happy customer but IMHO the application is absolutely worth its price. And there is a free trial so you can easily check whether it suits your needs.